# I can't get kinect sdk to do speech recognition and track skeletal data at the sime time

Tags: kinect, speech-recognition, speech

I' ve a program in witch I enabled speech recognition with..

```
        RecognizerInfo ri = GetKinectRecognizer();

        speechRecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ri.Id);

        // Create a grammar from grammar definition XML file.
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileContent)))
        {
            var g = new Grammar(memoryStream);
            speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(g);
        }

        speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(speechEngine_SpeechRecognized);
        speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognitionRejected += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs>(speechEngine_SpeechRecognitionRejected);
```

speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToAudioStream(
                    sensor.AudioSource.Start(), new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(EncodingFormat.Pcm, 16000, 16, 1, 32000, 2, null));

```
        speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

..

all'is working fine and SpeechRecognized  event get fired correctly..

The problem is, when I anable skeletal data tracking,

```
          sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
          sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
          sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += sensor_SkeletonFrameReady;
```

speech recognition stops working ...

can I get your help?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What are the system specs of your computer?  Both the speech recognized and the skeleton tracker take a good chunk of processing power.  You may be taxing your CPU too much.

Comment: It's a macbooc pro 13 inches

Comment: Are you just enabling tracking or are you doing something else with the Skeleton frame which could be hanging your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio is not processed if skeleton stream is enabled after starting audio capture
Due to a bug, enabling or disabling the SkeletonStream will stop the AudioSource stream returned by the Kinect sensor. The following sequence of instructions will stop the audio stream:
            kinectSensor.Start();
            kinectSensor.AudioSource.Start(); // --> this will create an audio stream
            kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(); // --> this will stop the audio stream as an undesired side effect

The workaround is to invert the order of the calls or to restart the AudioSource after changing SkeletonStream status.

```
        Workaround #1 (start audio after skeleton):
        kinectSensor.Start();
        kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
        kinectSensor.AudioSource.Start();

        Workaround #2 (restart audio after skeleton):
        kinectSensor.Start();
        kinectSensor.AudioSource.Start(); // --> this will create an audio stream
        kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(); // --> this will stop the audio stream as an undesired side effect
        kinectSensor.AudioSource.Start(); // --> this will create another audio stream
```

Source - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663798.aspx