# Kinect speech recognition and skeleton tracking don't work together

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling, kinect-sdk

I'm writing an application that can take several different external inputs (keyboard presses, motion gestures, speech) and produce similar outputs (for instance, pressing "T" on the keyboard will do the same thing as saying the word "Travel" out loud). Because of that, I don't want any of the input managers to know about each other. Specifically, I don't want the Kinect manager (as much as possible) to know about the Speech manager and vice versa, even though I'm using the Kinect's built-in microphone (the Speech manager should work with ANY microphone). I'm using System.Speech in the Speech manager as opposed to Microsoft.Speech.

I'm having a problem where as soon as the Kinect motion recognition module is enabled, the speech module stops receiving input. I've tried a whole bunch of things like [inverting the skeleton stream and audio stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046729/i-cant-get-kinect-sdk-to-do-speech-recognition-and-track-skeletal-data-at-the-s), capturing the audio stream in different ways, etc. I finally narrowed down the problem: something about how I'm initializing my modules does not play nicely with how my application deals with events.

The application works great until motion capture starts. If I completely exclude the Kinect module, this is how my main method looks:

```
    // Main.cs
    public static void Main()
    {

        // Create input managers
        KeyboardMouseManager keymanager = new KeyboardMouseManager();
        SpeechManager speechmanager = new SpeechManager();

        // Start listening for keyboard input
        keymanager.start();    

        // Start listening for speech input
        speechmanager.start()

        try
        {
           Application.Run();  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

I'm using `Application.Run()` because my GUI is handled by an outside program. This C# application's only job is to receive input events and run external scripts based on that input.

Both the keyboard and speech modules receive events sporadically. The Kinect, on the other hand, generates events constantly. If my gestures happened just as infrequently, a polling loop might be the answer with a wait time between each poll. However, I'm using the Kinect to control mouse movement... I can't afford to wait between skeleton event captures, because then the mouse would be very laggy; my skeleton capture loop needs to be as constant as possible. This presented a big problem, because now I can't have my Kinect manager on the same thread (or message pump? I'm a little hazy on the difference, hence why I think the problem lies here): from the way I understand it, being on the same thread would not allow keyboard or speech events to consistently get through. Instead, I kind of hacked together a solution where I made my Kinect manager inherit from `System.Windows.Forms`, so that it would work with `Application.Run()`.
Now, my main method looks like this:

```
    // Main.cs
    public static void Main()
    {

        // Create input managers
        KeyboardMouseManager keymanager = new KeyboardMouseManager();
        KinectManager kinectManager = new KinectManager();
        SpeechManager speechmanager = new SpeechManager();

        // Start listening for keyboard input
        keymanager.start();

        // Attempt to launch the kinect sensor
        bool kinectLoaded = kinectManager.start();


        // Use the default microphone (if applicable) if kinect isn't hooked up
        // Use the kinect microphone array if the kinect is working
        if (kinectLoaded)
        {
           speechmanager.start(kinectManager);
        }
        else
        {
           speechmanager.start();
        }


        try
        {
           // THIS IS THE PLACE I THINK I'M DOING SOMETHING WRONG
           Application.Run(kinectManager);  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

For some reason, the Kinect microphone loses its "default-ness" as soon as the Kinect sensor is started (if this observation is incorrect, or there is a workaround, PLEASE let me know). Because of that, I was required to make a special `start()` method in the Speech manager, which looks like this:

```
    // SpeechManager.cs

    /** For use with the Kinect Microphone **/
    public void start(KinectManager kinect)
    {
        // Get the speech recognizer information
        RecognizerInfo recogInfo = SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers().FirstOrDefault();

        if (null == recogInfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: No recognizer information found on Kinect");
            return;
        }

        SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(recogInfo.Id);

        // Loads all of the grammars into the recognizer engine
        loadSpeechBindings(recognizer);

        // Set speech event handler
        recognizer.SpeechRecognized += speechRecognized;

        using (var s = kinect.getAudioSource().Start() )
        {
            // Set the input to the Kinect audio stream
            recognizer.SetInputToAudioStream(s, new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(EncodingFormat.Pcm, 16000, 16, 1, 32000, 2, null));

            // Recognize asycronous speech events
            recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
    }
```

For reference, the `start()` method in the Kinect manager looks like this:

```
    // KinectManager.cs
    public bool start()
    {
        // Code from Microsoft Sample
        kinect = (from sensorToCheck in KinectSensor.KinectSensors where sensorToCheck.Status == KinectStatus.Connected select sensorToCheck).FirstOrDefault();

        // Fail elegantly if no kinect is detected
        if (kinect == null)
        {
            connected = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find a Kinect");
            return false;
        }

        // Start listening
        kinect.Start();

        // Enable listening for all skeletons
        kinect.SkeletonStream.Enable();

        // Obtain the KinectAudioSource to do audio capture
        source = kinect.AudioSource;
        source.EchoCancellationMode = EchoCancellationMode.None; // No AEC for this sample
        source.AutomaticGainControlEnabled = false; // Important to turn this off for speech recognition

        kinect.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(allFramesReady);

        connected = true;
        return true;
    }
```

So when I disable motion capture (by having my main() look similar to the first code segment), speech recognition works fine. When I enable motion capture, motion works great but no speech gets recognized. In both cases, keyboard events always work. There are no errors, and through tracing I found out that all the data in the speech manager is initialized correctly... it *seems* like the speech recognition events just disappear. How can I reorganize this code so that the input modules can work independently? Do I use threading, or just Application.Run() in a different way?

Comment: Which SDK and which Kinect are you using: XBox or Windows? Also, which version of the Speech API are you using?

Comment: I'm using the SDK version 1, and I'm using the kinect on Windows. I'm using System.Speech version 4

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Kinect SDK have several [known issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663798.aspx), one of them being that audio is not processed if you begin tracking the skeleton after starting the audio processor.  From the known issues:

```
Audio is not processed if skeleton stream is enabled after starting audio capture

Due to a bug, enabling or disabling the SkeletonStream will stop the AudioSource
stream returned by the Kinect sensor. The following sequence of instructions will
stop the audio stream:
    kinectSensor.Start();
    kinectSensor.AudioSource.Start(); // --> this will create an audio stream
    kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(); // --> this will stop the audio stream as an undesired side effect

The workaround is to invert the order of the calls or to restart the AudioSource after changing SkeletonStream status.
    Workaround #1 (start audio after skeleton):
    kinectSensor.Start();
    kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
    kinectSensor.AudioSource.Start();

    Workaround #2 (restart audio after skeleton):
    kinectSensor.Start();
    kinectSensor.AudioSource.Start(); // --> this will create an audio stream
    kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(); // --> this will stop the audio stream as an undesired side effect
    kinectSensor.AudioSource.Start(); // --> this will create another audio stream

Resetting the SkeletonStream engine status is an expensive call. It should be made at application startup only, unless the app has specific needs that require turning Skeleton on and off.
```

I also hope that when you say you're using "version 1" of the SDK, you mean "version 1.6".  If you are using anything but 1.5 or 1.6, you are only hurting yourself due to the many changes that were made in 1.5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did mention at the top of my question, though, that I already tried this and it didn't really change anything. After looking more into my SDK version, I think you're right that I had a way outdated one. Let me try updating it and seeing what happens

Comment: Sorry, missed the mention of the audio/skeleton init order... it was a long post. :)